# Arcpy and pyqgis on same IDE

Tags: arcpy, pyqgis, installation, pycharm, importerror

I have question: is it possible to set up arcpy and pyqgis on the same IDE (I use Pycharm).
I have some problem with running my pyqgis scripts from pycharm. When I first configure Pycharm to recognize pyqgis (I set pythonpaths) everything works well, but after program restart I got this: `ImportError: No module named qgis.core` Is there any solution to this?